# Why do I get error 302 if I don't include a "Accept": 'application/json' header in the fetch request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

Even when I don't include the accept header, my request works and returns the data that I need, however it gets redirected, why?

Comment: This question can't be answered without seeing the code responsible for responding to requests on the server.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't specify the `Accept` header, the server isn't sure that you've asked for JSON, so it answers with `302 Found` because it may not be file for what you looked for.